# Excel/VBA - open not as read only

Tags: excel, vba

I need to construct a workbook that opens two separate workbooks, each in a separate instance of Excel, and run the macro in their respective workbooks.

After some research, I got:

```
Sub runMacro()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False


Dim appXL As New Excel.Application

appXL.Workbooks.Open Filename:="E:\ExcelFiles\Workbook1.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=True, ReadOnly:=False
appXL.ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = True
appXL.Visible = True
appXL.Application.Run ("'Workbook1.xlsm'!Macro1")


End Sub
```

The code does not produce an error is able to run the correct subprocedure in the correct instance of Excel, however the workbook is opened in read-only mode. I have tried a few more different syntax but they either resulted in an error or had no effect.

Comment: The file is made read-only whenever the file is in use. Even using multiple instances of the `Application` class, I don't think you can circumvent this.

Comment: @DavidZemens So in other words, if I try to save the workbook in Macro1, it will result in an error and will fail?

Comment: Only 1 process can acquire a write lock on a file at any given time, so yes.

Comment: @DavidZemens I don't think I am understanding correctly as to what the write lock is. For me, I am able to open two instances of Excel manually by holding down Alt button, and run both macros when the workbooks are not opened as Read-Only. I googled "write lock", and didn't see how it will affect the current situation. Could you elaborate a bit more on this?

Comment: What others are trying to tell you is that if the _file_ is already open in any instance of excel it will open as read only.  Is that the case here?  Other possible reasons it might open read only are: it's set to open read only, it requires a password for write access, the folder it's in is read only...

Comment: @chrisneilsen But I do not have the file opened in any other instance of Excel. I can double click and open it without any issue.

Comment: @user101998 Ok, I've tried your code: file opens read/write for me.  Try removing `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` to see if there are any alerts being supressed that are relavent

Comment: the file could be open by any other user assuming E is mapped to a shared network drive. the file could be open in an orphaned instance of excel e.g. from previous debugging attempts etc.